# Por que ele pula para o próximo bloco de comando?

Tags: java

```
String login = sc.next();

while (login == "kauan") {
    System.out.println("acesso permitido");
    login = sc.next();
}

System.out.println("Acesso negado");

sc.close();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String senha = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("digite a senha:");
        int contador = 1;

        while(senha.equals("kauan") && contador<=2) {
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("senha incorreta, tente novamente : /n tentativas restante :"+ (3-contador));
            contador++;
        }

        System.out.println();
        if(senha.equals("kauan"))   {
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"acesso permitido:");
        }else {
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"acesso negado:");
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).